# CSS3 translate out of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a number of projects now I have had elements on the page which I want to translate out of the screen area (have them fly out of the document). In proper code this should be possible just by adding a class to the relevant element after which the css would handle the rest. The problem lies in the fact that if for example

```
.block.hide{
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-10000px);
}
```

is used the element will first of all fly out of the screen unnecessarily far and with an unnecessarily high speed. And purely from an aesthetic point of view there's a lot left to be desired (Theoretically speaking for example a screen with a height of 10000px could be introduced one day in the future).

(Update) The problem why percentages can't be used is that 100% is relative to the element itself, rather than to the parent element/screen size. And containing the element in a full-sized parent would be possible, but would create a mess with click events. And after a few answers, allow me to point out that I am talking about translations, not about `position:absolute` css3 transitions (which are all fine, but once you get enough of them they stop being fun).

What aesthetically pleasing solutions to allow an element to translate out of a screen in a fixed amount of time can you guys think of?

Example code can be found in this jsfiddle demonstrating the basic concept.
http://jsfiddle.net/ATcpw/

*(see my own answer below for a bit more information)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I did is use the `vh` (view height) unit. It's always relative to the screen size, not the element itself:

```
/* moves the element one screen height down */
translateY(calc(100vh))
```

So if you know the position of the element in the screen (say `top:320px`), you can move it exactly off the screen:

```
/* moves the element down exactly off the bottom of the screen */
translateY(calc(100vh - 320px))
```

Comment: this was the best option for me but I didn't know the position on screen of the element so I just used `translateY(100vh)`. 

in css, you have the option to set two different transitions based on what class the element has so this allowed me to adjust the timing/easing so that the animation looks smooth when it leaves and when it enters regardless of how far you are transitioning the element to or from.

Answer (score 13):

If you wrap the .block div with a container:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

you could expand and then, translate the container itself **after** the click event

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
   document.querySelector(".container").classList.add("hide");
});
```

with this style

```
.block {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
    left:10px;
    height:100px;
    background:gray;
}

.container {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-in-out 1s;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s; /* Needed to calculate the vertical area to shift with translateY */
}

.container.hide {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    /* background:#f00; /* Uncomment to see the affected area */ 
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-110%);
}
```

In this way, it is possible to apply a correct translationY percentage ( a little more than 100%, just to have it out of the way ) and mantaining the button clickable.

You could see a working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/MG7bK/

P.S: I noticed that the transition delay is needed only for the transitionY property, otherwise the animation would fail, probably because it tries to start before having an actual value for the height. It could be omitted if you use the horizontal disappearing, with translateX.

Comment: Genius idea as well :D, though I seriously dislike the idea of the delay this is a solution which is quite pleasing, the only disadvantage being the necessity to wrap it with a container div, but kudos for coming up with this!

Comment: Awarded bounty to this answer, because it was the answer which most relevantly and geniusly answered the question, despite the fact that I would not advise the use of this technique.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is not exactly what you were asking but...

Would you consider using CSS animations with [Greensock's Animation Platform](http://www.greensock.com/css3/)? It is terribly fast (it claims it's 20 times faster than jQuery), you can see the speed test here: http://www.greensock.com/js/speed.html

It would make your code nicer I believe, and instead of trying to hack CSS animations you could focus on more important stuff.

I have created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ATcpw/4/

Both CSS and possible JS look simpler:

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
    var toAnimate = document.querySelector(".block");
    TweenMax.to(toAnimate, 2, {y: -window.innerHeight});
});
```

CSS:

```
.block{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
    left:10px;
    height:100px;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/100);
}
```

Comment: Looks more interesting then I first expected, at the very least the idea of abstracting it away to a library is a fair one. It seems that greensock is updating the translation though through `requestAnimationFrame`... which is kinda neat though it ends up lacking the power of transitions.

Comment: `TweenMax` has been the industry standard for animation for years. Recently it has been re-written in JS. Personally, I use it every time the animation is a little bit complex. It gives so much more control over all the parameters that I can't imagine trying to code it in CSS `key frames`. You can control speed, delay, easing, frame rate and much more. Greensock's library has been also the fastest. I would recommend it with all my heart.

Comment: Yeah, the way it technically works is pretty neat, though as far as speed goes `key frames` would probably still win, but the difference is pretty very small. Either way, I have to say that looking a bit closer at their animation platform I am quite impressed overall. A lot more impressed than I expected to be :P .

Comment: Awarded accepted answer to this answer, because despite the answer not being 100% an answer to the posed question, the given technique seems to be the most advisable one in most use cases.

Comment: @DavidMulder [This thread](http://forums.greensock.com/topic/7429-tweening-inherited-values/) illustrates why I love the Greensock's platform.

Answer (score 4):

I recently built an app which used precisely this technique for sliding 'panels' (or pages) and tabs of the application in and out of view. [A basic implementation of the tabs mechanism can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/EJ7ve/).

Basically (pesudo-code to illustrate the concept, minus prefixes etc):

```
.page {
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

.page.active {
    transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

[The problem I had was that Android Webkit in particular wouldn't calculate percentage values correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156805/force-correct-css3-transform-percentage-interpretation-on-android). In the end I had to use script to grab the viewport width and specify the value in pixels, then [write the rules using a library for dynamic stylesheet parsing](https://github.com/Box9/jss).

But eventually, and in spite of only these minor platform-specific problems, this worked perfectly for me.

Comment: It seems I didn't specify the problem precisely enough, the problem is that percentages are calculated respective to the size of the element, which is fine for an element with a 100% viewport height, but not for any other element. And wrapping it in a parent element with that size isn't an option due to click events on the area around the element.

Comment: In that case it sounds like the dynamic stylesheets may be the way to go. I'll try and dig that script up and update my answer.

Comment: I already did that in my answer (see below), but I was wondering about a solution which wouldn't mix style with script... well, going to wait and see whether somebody else comes up with something good, otherwise I will just go with your answer.

Comment: I was looking, on and off, for a month :( (and as you can see, my original question's tumbleweed). I can't find the exact code I used — I've since lost access to the project source (was on contract) and my laptop with a local checkout bricked. But essentially, in pseudo-code, you'd write a function that determined viewport dimensions and wrote the style rule dynamically on DOM ready and then throttle it (avoid stackoverflow on desktop) on window resize (which takes account of orientation change). Not ideal, but the [JSS lib](https://github.com/Box9/jss) makes it cleaner to read and manage.

Answer (score 1):

Use `calc` method (http://jsfiddle.net/ATcpw/2/):

```
.block{
    position:absolute;
    top: -webkit-calc(100% - 110px);
    right:10px;
    left:10px;
    height:100px;
    background:gray;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    /*this adds GPU acceleration*/
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0); 
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.block.hide{
    top: -100px;
}
```

Since you are using `-webkit` prefix I used it as well.
`calc` is supported by majority of browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: I was talking about GPU accelerated translations, not about re-positioning an absolutely positioned element...

Comment: From your question I understood that you wanted to move the box out of the screen in a nice way. You didn't mention the need of GPU acceleration. If you want, you can add: `transform: translate3d(0,0,0); -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to `.block` class, then the animation will be GPU accelerated.

Comment: No it won't, I was talking about *translations* with a reason. Forcing GPU rendering only is useful when you're transforming elements, with position absolute they are moved through the DOM. I mean, I mention in the title, the body and the tags that I am talking about css3 translations.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple, but not aesthetically pleasing solution is to define the class dynamically:

```
var stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var ruleBlockHide;
```

and

```
//onresize
if(ruleBlockHide) stylesheet.deleteRule(ruleBlockHide);
ruleBlockHide = stylesheet.insertRule('.block.hide{ -webkit-transform:translateY(-'+window.innerHeight+'px); }',stylesheet.cssRules.length);
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/PDU7T/

The reason a reference to the rule needs to be kept is that after each screen resize the rule has to be deleted and re-added.

Although this solution gets the job done, there has to be some DOM/CSS combination which would allow this to be done without javascript (something along the lines of a 100%x100% element containing such a block, but I haven't been able to figure out any transform based way).

Answer (score -1):

get the document width. then use a java script trigger to trigger the css3 translation.

```
       function translate(){

       var width = document.body.Width;
        document.getElementById('whateverdiv').style='translateX(' + width + 'px)';

       }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is simple
add the following to your div

```
.myDiv {
    -webkit-transition-property: left;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: initial
}
```

then change the "left" property of it either by adding an additional class or by jQuery

This will animate it along the x-axis

**Note:** you can change the -webkit-transition-property to any property you want and this will animate it