# Best way to translate an element off-screen?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I've been using CSS3 transforms for a while now but one thing that has been a slight bugbear is that percentages relate to the element you're moving, rather than the parent element. This makes sense but it brings about a few situations I'm not sure the best way of solving.

For example, if we were to imagine an element absolutely positioned on the screen, how would you go about transitioning that element off-screen? The dimensions of the element could be something small like 200x200 pixels, meaning you couldn't use percentages without doing some calculations.

The options I've whittled it down to in my head are:

1) Put the element inside a container that is the size of the screen, then translate the container by 100%.

2) Promote the element to its own GPU layer with translateZ, will-change, or translate3d, then apply appropriate left/right properties.

3) Use getBoundingClientRect to determine where the element is in relation to the viewport, do a calculation to determine the distance in pixels that would need to be applied in order to make the element leave the screen, then apply that value as an inline translate style.

Could I please get some advice on the best way to handle a situation like this? Factors to consider are that the technique would be used in a responsive site, so any value calculating would need to be done immediately prior to applying the technique.

Comment: Do you have a "largest supported resolution" or something? If it doesn't matter *how much* off-screen you translate your element, you could use a sufficiently huge absolute offset, and just move the element, say, 10 000 pixels left or right. (And by the way, is there a good reason you can't just use `display: none`?)

Comment: @TomasLycken - The problem with that approach would be that you couldn't control the speed of that animation very well! There's no largest resolution in particular; the question applies to any size of resolution.

Comment: Thought I'd share this link for reference sake:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317020/css3-translate-out-of-screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do to position something off-screen or outside of the parent is to use position properties.  To me this seems natural; top/left/right/bottom are animatable, so they transition nicely; and the third benefit is that there is great support for these properties, so even if the browser is ancient the fallback is the positioning works just not the transition.

Consider the following:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="from-the-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative; /*Make sure the parent has positioning*/
    overflow: hidden; /*Hide its overflow*/
}

.from-the-bottom {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;  /*100% top pushes the element fully out of view at the bottom*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    transition: top .3s ease;
}

.parent:hover .from-the-bottom {
    top: 0; /*Changing the top value positions the element within the context of it's parent*/
}
```

Comment: But top/right/left/bottom won't be GPU accelerated right, and cause repaints?

Comment: Correct, hence your option 2.  I should have been more clear.  Again, the benefit in my mind is that it will degrade gracefully and of course it also works against the parent element.

Comment: Do you know of any performance differences between using translateZ + top/left/right/bottom, and translate3d/translate?

I always hear of people saying you should use translate to move everything, but no-one has ever mentioned using transformZ + top.

Comment: I remember Paul Irish did a performance test -- but thinking back it might have been a comparison between animating top/left with jQuery vs. CSS.  I'll have to take a look.  I suppose I should have asked first, but what is your goal here?  Is it heavy animation you're looking to optimize?  Maybe something like velocity.js is something you should look at using.  Do you want good support across most browsers and devices?  It just seems to be a really subjective question.

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Comment: In that video he never promoted the top/left layer to the GPU, so i'm wondering if he did, would he have had the same results as the translate stuff.

My use case is that I often have screens on applications where they have some centered content, and theres a transition to a new screen such as a swipe or slide. It feels wrong to make a full-screen container element and translate it rather than the much-smaller element thats centered on the page. I worry that these big (yet mostly empty) container elements getting promoted would take up more GPU memory.

Comment: Okay, so that's a bit different than my understanding of the OP. In that case I probably wouldn't use positioning, but just because it wouldn't seem as natural to me, not because of particular performance benefits.  And, I guess that use-case also it limits the browsers that you care about (i.e., you're not talking about IE8/IE9).

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
.offscreen {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
 }
```

---

`position: fixed` is placing the element relative to the viewport (browser window). Think of `fixed` as being the same as `absolute`, *except* it's the relative to the viewport, ignoring all other divs.

Then we place the element on the top left corner with `top: 0` and `left: 0`

We have this:

```
          ______________
         |[Element]     |
         |              |
         |              |
         |  (Viewport)  | 
         |              |
         |              |
         |______________|
```

Then we move the element to the left by 100% of its own width, thus effectively hiding it from view, with `transform: translateX(-100%)`:

```
          ______________
[Element]|              |
         |              |
         |              |
         |  (Viewport)  | 
         |              |
         |              |
         |______________|
```

*Note: This is not affected by zooming in/out and also does not cause overflow (scrolling).*